# What is the probability that a Brownian motion will cross level $1$ before time $T$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

The following question is taken from Mark Joshi's Quant Job Inteview.

> Question: What is the probability that a Brownian motion will cross level $1$ before time $t$?
>
> (A follow up question): What is the probability that a Brownian motion will eventually cross the level $1$ (that is, the limit as $t\to\infty)?$

Let
$$M(t) = \max_{0\leq s\leq t}W(t)$$
where $(W(t))_{t\geq 0}$ is Brownian motion.

Note that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(M(t) \geq 1) & =  \mathbb{P}(M(t) \geq 1, W(t) \geq 1) + \mathbb{P}(M_t \geq 1, W(t) \leq 1) \\
& = \mathbb{P}(M(t) \geq 1, W(t) \geq 1).
\end{align*}

If the first passage time of Brownian motion at level $1$ is denoted by
$$\tau_1 = \inf\{t\geq 0: W(t) = 1\},$$
then
$$M(t) \geq 1 \quad \Leftrightarrow \tau_1 \leq t.$$
So,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(M(t) \geq 1, W(t) \geq 1) & = \mathbb{P}(\tau_1 \leq t, W(t) \geq 1) \\
& = \mathbb{P}(W(t) \geq 1).
\end{align*}
So, I got
$$\mathbb{P}(W(t) \geq 1).$$
However, answer given in the book is
$$2\mathbb{P}(W(t) \geq 1).$$

I do not see where is my mistake in my calculations above.

---

As pointed out by @NateEldredge in comment below, the probability
$$\mathbb{P}(M(t) \geq 1, W(t) \leq 1) \neq 0.$$
In fact,
$$\mathbb{P}(M(t) \geq 1, W(t) \leq 1) = \mathbb{P}(M(t) \geq 1, W(t) \geq 1).$$
This justifies the factor $2$ of the final answer.

Comment: Why did you drop the term $\mathbb{P}(M_t \geq 1, W(t) \leq 1)$?  This probability isn't zero.  It's entirely possible that the value of the Brownian motion goes above 1, then drops below again and finishes below 1 at time 1.

Comment: Indeed, the standard way to solve this problem is to observe by the reflection principle that $\mathbb{P}(M(t) \geq 1, W(t) \geq 1) = \mathbb{P}(M_t \geq 1, W(t) \leq 1)$, and this is where the factor of 2 comes from.

Comment: @NateEldredge I see my mistake now. Thanks.

Comment: @NateEldredge I added a follow up question. Wonder whether you can give some hint on how to solve it.

Comment: Let $\tau = \inf\{t \geq 0: B_t = 1\}$ be the hitting time of $1$. Then your follow up question is "what is $\mathbb{P}(\tau < \infty)$?". $\mathbb{P}(\tau < \infty) = \mathbb{P}(\bigcup_{n \geq 0} \{\tau < n\}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(\tau < n)$. Your first question was to compute the quantity appearing in this limit.

Comment: @RhysSteele Yes, I am aware that I need to find the limit of $\mathbb{P}(\tau<n)$. However, I am not able to compute the limit.

Comment: $W(n)$ is centered Gaussian with variance $n$ so you can express $\mathbb{P}(W(n) \geq 1)$ as an integral. Try performing a suitable change of variables in this integral and taking the limit.

Comment: As to your follow up question, you have now shown that $P(M(t) \ge 1) = 2P(W(t) \ge 1)$.  The latter is equal, via the usual Brownian scaling, to $2P(W(1) \ge t^{-1/2})$.  Sending $t \to \infty$ you conclude that the desired probability equals $2 P(W(1) > 0) = 1$.  This is the famous fact that 1-D Brownian motion is recurrent: it is a.s. guaranteed to hit every point.